# How to share frame rendering between two proceses

Tags: c++, design-patterns, render, ipc

Im designing a game menu for an arcade machine as a personal project and to get more familiar with IPC. The project runs on a raspberry Pi rendering to a LED matrix using [Hzeller's](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix) led matrix library. The menu would present the user a list of games rendered on the matrix. When the user selects a game, the main process will fork and spawn the game in a new process. The game will start and render to the matrix. At any point the user can exit the game which will return the user back to the game menu. Presumably there will be communication between processes so each aren't simultaneously rendering to the matrix at the same time.

Now where I am uncertain is how to actually share resources that are needed to render to the matrix. The library has a background updater thread that cannot be running in both process. Im not certain how this is typically done but here are the solutions I came up with:

1. Resources needed for rendering are cleaned up and reinitialized before switching contexts between parent and child processes
2. The Child will serialize the underlying framebuffer data and send it to the main process for rendering.

The first solution seems a little hacky and requires me to make small changes to the library. I also want to create an interface to decouple the menu/game processes from where graphics are actually rendered. This way I can make a separate implementation of the interface to render to a GUI on a computer screen. Choosing this option would be synonymous of creating an entirely new window for the child process (not sharing the same window).

The second solution would require copying the framebuffer data twice per frame. Once to shared memory and then again when the parent process copies out of shared memory and rendered. I worry about latency and how to manage frame rate in this solution. Ive looked into initializing the framebuffer in shared memory, but the library handles the initiation of this buffer. In addition, I am utilizing the library's vsync capability and am unsure how the child would utilize this if rendering were done in the parent process

My questions are:

- Are there any other solutions? If not which of the two are better
  design wise.
- If I go option two, how would the child take advantage of the vsync functionality and how would I manage framerate in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

A game will typically involve real-time rendering to the LED matrix, and will have other requirements for user interaction to that are specific to the game and a lot more demanding than the requirements of your simple menu.  It would not be good design practice to delegate these things to the menu process via some IPC mechanism.  That mechanism could only get in the way, and you'd be forced to implement many of the game's requirements inside the menu process.  The game should be able to control the display directly, while the menu should only have to do its easy menu things.

This should be very simple to arrange.  Your menu process should shut down its display loop before it launches the game process, and should then resume its display loop when the game process ends.

The best way to do detect the completion of the child process is usually to pipe stdout on the child process into a parent process file handle.  The parent process should read from this handle until it is automatically closed by the child process exiting.  This is a universally reliable signal that works on all linux/unix/windows platforms.